# Relative path of keystore

Tags: android, gradle, apk, keystore

I signed my app and generated a signed keystore and an apk file. You can see the signing configurations of the app in the gradle file.

```
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'capstone'
        keyPassword 'pass1'
        storeFile file('/Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/capstone/Capstone-Udacity/capstoneproject.jks')
        storePassword 'pass2'
    }
}
```

Obviously, it won't run in your machine, as I store it locally. So the question is how to change the path of the keystore?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: `the question is how to change the path of the keystore?` Create a Another folder in another local drive.

Comment: yes. that's the question

Comment: When you say local drive where exactly do you suggest? I am using Mac OS

Comment: Do you want to keep the keystore in git so anyone cloning the project would be able to assemble the app with the keystore you provide? Move the keystore file in the root folder of your project and then you could simply use file("$project.rootDir/the_keystore_file").

Comment: I fixed it using this:  storeFile file("$rootDir/capstoneproject.jks")